# partial-ized forward method for a torch Model does not work well with multi-gpu jobs

Tags: pytorch, huggingface-trainer

I am trying to understand why re-assigning the forward method of a pytorch model object leads to the following error under multi-gpu prediction job (configured automatically by huggingface trainer)

> RuntimeError: Expected all tensors to be on
> the same device, but found at least two devices, cuda:0 and cuda:1!
> (when checking argument for argument index in method
> wrapper_CUDA__index_select)

This happens when I re-assign the forward method of my model object like so

```
model = CustomModel(...)
partial_kwargs = {'key1': value1, ..}
model.forward = partial(model.forward, **partial_kwargs)
```

If instead I pass `partial_kwargs` as constructor kwargs of `CustomModel`, I don't get the cuda device error above.

Please let me know if anything is unclear in the description and I can add more context.
[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68344572/pytorch-custom-forward-function-does-not-work-with-dataparallel) seems related but not the same, as I did not explicitly assign specific cuda devices in any part of the code.